# c++ using maps to sort a notepads characters

Tags: c++

I'm looking to sort a text file by using a map to find how many of each character is in the text file. I think I'm pretty close.

```
void CharStatistic(string filename)
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(filename);
    char x;
    int i;
    map <char, int> count;
    while (infile >> x)
    {
        count[x]++;
        for (auto it = count.begin(); it != count.end(); it++)
            cout << it->first << it->second << endl;

    }
}
```

here's what is actually in the file im reading.

```
Computer science is the scientific and practical approach to computation and its applications. It is the systematic study of the feasibility, structure, expression, and mechanization of the methodical procedures (or algorithms) that underlie the acquisition, representation, processing, storage, communication of, and access to information, whether such information is encoded as bits in a computer memory or transcribed in genes and protein structures in a biological cell. An alternate, more succinct definition of computer science is the study of automating algorithmic processes that scale. A computer scientist specializes in the theory of computation and the design of computational systems.

    Its subfields can be divided into a variety of theoretical and practical disciplines. Some fields, such as computational complexity theory (which explores the fundamental properties of computational and intractable problems), are highly abstract, while fields such as computer graphics emphasize real-world visual applications. Still other fields focus on the challenges in implementing computation. For example, programming language theory considers various approaches to the description of computation, while the study of computer programming itself investigates various aspects of the use of programming language and complex systems. Human-computer interaction considers the challenges in making computers and computations useful, usable, and universally accessible to humans.
```

If all possible I'd also like to figure out how to print out the character with the most occurrence. And as always much appreciated for any help!

Comment: scan the map `count`, and find the one with maximum value

Comment: Your code tallies up the frequency of individual non-whitespace characters, but what on earth do you mean by *"looking to sort"* the file?  Sorting by characters is rarely useful/desired, is it really what you mean... something like `AAABBCCCCCFHH...aaaaaaabbbccee`?  If not, what?

Comment: I mean I'm trying to see how many of each character. Like a 1 b 3 c 24 ect... hopefully that clears it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct your code

```
void CharStatistic(string filename) {
    ifstream infile(filename);
    if (!infile.is_open()) return;    // Check if file opened correctly
    char x;
    map<char, int> count;
    while (infile >> x) count[x]++;
    for (auto it : count)    // Pull this out of the while loop
        cout << it.first << " " << it.second << endl;
}
```

To find the max occurrence

```
int max = *max_element(count.begin(), count.end(), count.value_comp());
```

Comment: Do I need a library for that max occurrence bit? I get no suitable conversion function error on the " * "

Comment: @SaladSnake `#include <algorithm>` will do it.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use a `map` in this case. With only 256 values, a simple array occupies only 1 kilobyte (assuming 4 bytes for each count). Even though the input might be sparse, so some elements of that array go unused, at only 1 K, you're unlikely to gain anything by using a different structure.

Once you've done the counting, transforming to an array of structures you can sort by the counts is pretty easy (or, if you really only need the one with the largest count, just do a linear scan for that one).

Answer (score 1):

- Don't print the values of map every time in your loop.
- To print the highest frequencies in order, dump your map content to 'std::vector' of std::pair' and sort it with a comparator comparing values based on second element of pair.
- Finally display the sorted vector.

Comment: I get an error with the iterator when I take the cout line out of the loop. Sorry im kind of new to this stuff.

Comment: @SaladSnake: move the `for` loop *and* `cout` lines.

Comment: Thanks tony and P0W that worked great. I feel so dumb haha simple mistake.